# Does window OS required to run Wine and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7

I wanted to use ubuntu as my OS but Indiabulls trading platform is not supporting for on line trading. Alternatively I was told that "wine" will be helpfull. Does this mean that I need to have both windows OS and UBUNTU? actually what that means?

Comment: Questions and answers should be open and on this site. It is *not* similar to a helpdesk or -service.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Windows or a Windows license to use Wine. Still, not all Windows-software is usable with wine, as it works like a mediator between Linux and the software.

I don't know this Indiabulls thingy, but you could try it.

If Wine doesn't work, you could still run it in a virtual machine like VMware or VirtualBox. That would require a Windows license and is more inconvenient as it comes with more effort in daily use.